# Is there an alternative to the headless argument with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I've noticed that the `'--headless'` argument has caused many issues when using selenium and chromedriver with Python. For example, it doesn't let you download files from links you click on and some websites/webpages load slower or not at all. Can another method be used to get the same experience?

Comment: You could simply ignore `--headless` and have a Chrome window just run

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Thats defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do